# Swift Passing variable to Second View Controller With Inheritance

Tags: xcode, inheritance, swift3, uiviewcontroller

I have two view view controller; one inherits the other. VC1 has the variable lets say students that i have mutated within that view controller. VC2 inherits VC1. I have another variable in VC2 that I want to set to be the same as the variable in VC1. I have tried the options below but it always returns an unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value error. I know that the variable is not empty because I can print out its value in VC1 just fine. So what would i need to adjust in my code to correctly send the variable from VC1 to VC2?

In VC1:

```
    var students: [Student]!
func setmystud(changeme: [Student]) -> Void {
        var mechangeme = changeme
        mechangeme = students
    }
```

In VC2:

```
    var mystudents: [Student]!
override func viewDidLoad() {

       super.setmystud(changeme: mystudents)
        print(mystudents.count) //returns the error
    //OTHER TRY//  mystudents = super.students
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding of inheritance. The fact that `VC2` inherits from `VC1` means it has the same properties, but that doesn't mean it has the same values for those properties. If you had two instances of `VC1`, they also wouldn't share property values.

If you want to set values in an instance of `VC2`, you will need to pass those values to that specific instance of `VC2`.

The difference between classes and instances, and the basics of class inheritance is a foundational idea in object oriented programming (in any language). If you're having trouble with this, you should pause for a moment and make sure you understand the basics of OOP. Almost every piece of documentation assumes you already have that background. It is not obvious information; it's just assumed that you've already learned it.

A good introduction is [App Development in Swift](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/app-development-with-swift/id1219117996?mt=11). These concepts are introduced in Lesson 12.